# Can Someone Explain the Difference in two Python Commands?

Tags: python

I want to do a `subprocess.call` to create a file (and eventually populate it). Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import subprocess
import psycopg2
import base64
import urlparse
sys.path.append('/var/www/cgi-bin')

def index(req):
    out = ""

    mkFile = str("touch /etc/httpd/conf/ipForward/90.conf")
    subprocess.call([mkFile],shell=True)

    return out

mkFile = str("touch /etc/httpd/conf/ipForward/111.conf")
subprocess.call([mkFile],shell=True)
```

Right now only the bottom command works, but these two subprocesses should do the same exact thing (I've named the file differently for testing purposes). I know there is a better way to do this but, for my own edification (and sanity) can someone explain the difference?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT COMPLETE CODE~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
    def index(req):
    out = ""
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='pwp' host='localhost' user='~~~' password='~~~~~'")
    c = conn.cursor()

    inClCN = str(req.subprocess_env['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN'])

    c.execute("select * from Users where cn = '{0}';".format(inClCN))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        port = row[0]

    mkFile = str("touch /etc/httpd/conf/ipForward/{0}.conf".format(port))
    subprocess.call([mkFile],shell=True)

    insert = r"""Listen {0}\n\n<VirtualHost _default_:{1}>\n\nDocumentRoot '/var/www/html/'\nDirectoryIndex indexAlex.py\n\nRewriteEngine On\n\nErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/error_log\nTransferLog /etc/httpd/logs/access_log\nLogLevel warn\n\n\nNSSVerifyClient require\n\nNSSEngine on\nNSSFIPS on\nNSSProtocol(MORE CONF STRING)</VirtualHost>""".format(port,port)

    confFile = str('echo "{0}" >> /etc/httpd/conf/ipForward/{1}.conf'.format(insert,port))

    subprocess.call([confFile],shell=True)

    return out
```

The only reason I need the req is to get the environmental variable from apache. I don't really know how that works but I've been using that in other code without subprocesses.

Comment: Are you ever actually calling the function `index` anywhere?

Comment: And if you aren't calling the function `index` anywhere, why are you expecting the contents of that function to be invoked?

Comment: How can I call it. What argument do I need for req?

Comment: Your comment on Pedro's answer suggests you're using someone else's code. Post that code. We can't tell you what `req` is supposed to be unless you show us where it comes from/how it's used.

Comment: Aside from the req index function and calling an apache environmental variable, I'm not using anyone else's code. I've just updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Your first call to `subprocess.call` is within a `def` statement. A `def` statement doesn't actually call anything under it right away, instead it defines a function, which is a block of code you can reuse anywhere else.

The first "call" to `subprocess.call` doesn't do anything because you are just defining it as part of a reusable piece of code, but never actually using this reusable piece of code.

If you want to "use" the first call, you need to call the function you just defined using `def`:

Add the following to the end of your script:

```
index(None)
```

and the "first" call should happen, but after the first.

You can read more about how the `def` statement works and about functions [here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html).

Comment: I tried putting index(None) but I get an error saying `name 'none' is not defined`. I also can't leave it empty because it requires an argument req. I need this function to use this command `port=str(req.subprocess_env['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN'])`

Comment: You need to edit your question and include a *complete* example. See [mcve].

Comment: If you are getting an error saying `none` is not defined that means you typoed `None`.

Comment: You're right, it was a typo, but I can't use None anyway because that has no attribute for subprocess_env.